# Moving oracle data to postgress - How to calculate size required

Tags: database, postgresql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to move Oracle Data to Postgres server. And I am trying to understand how big an instance I need.

For Oracle I got following when I requested size from my admin.

```
DB Segment size: 729 GB
Datafile size:  7160 GB
```

Should I use DB size or DataFile size. or is there a compression I should consider ?

Comment: Use segment size times two.

Comment: We don't really know exactly these sizes actually represents - not in relation to the application data that will be migrated.  Does this include the system objects - the data dictionary, etc. - that would not be migrated?  Do you applications have a significant amount of allocated but unused segment space?  Just throwing out a number in a vacuum without seeing the query that produced it is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

For starting take db segment size. Keep a good bit of growing space available. The application behavior and vacuum configuration have to fit otherwise your dead rows might grow over your head.
For big tables with lots of updates/deletes the default are way to slow.
What oracle does in undo comes close to what Postgres does with dead rows. It’s one of the things to monitor and tweak.
Archive space is very similar.
Does the db filesize include the temporary tablespaces?
In that case check how often you have them filled in recent times. Most of the times this is because some kind of query was out of control.